# Doctrine2 Unittest mock up entity in relationship

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create unittest of a service class - class which has EntityManager injected and is responsible for loading and creating entities.

The problem is in ::create(array) method for entities which creates entity and sets all required related entities. So I thought it would be advisable to use mock object for this, but when I use following code (also seen here: [How to create a mock object of a doctrine entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575902/how-to-create-a-mock-object-of-a-doctrine-entity))

```
<?php
public function testCreate($email, $password)
{
    $role = $this->getMock('Role');
    $this->service->create(
        array('email' => $email,
              'password' => $password,
              'role' => $role));
}

// service (simplified)
public function create(array $values)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setEmail($values['email'])
        ->setPassword($values['password'])
        ->setRole($values['role']);

    $this->getDatabaseManager()->persist($user)->flush();

    return $user;
}
?>
```

It triggers: **A new entity was found through a relationship that was not configured to cascade persist operations**

Using:

```
$this->service->getDatabaseManager()->persist($role);
```

in the test triggers: **Class Mock_Role_c64eda12 is not a valid entity or mapped super class.**

How can I either fix this or what better approach can I use? (don't know which one applies more here...if the whole 'service creates and persists entites' or whatever else is a bad idea please let me know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont want to mock the Role here, you want to mock the EntityManager. If you don't want to mock the entity manager you are in a functional test, in this case you can also work with the real Role object.